# query to find a partial match

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a query to find all the items in my `'schedule_items'` table that match a `YYYY-MM-DD` value of a `DATETIME` field.

something like: `SELECT * FROM`schedule_items`WHERE`start`?matches? '$date'`

Where  start would be a `DATETIME` field with data like `2009-09-23 11:34:00` and `$date` would be something like 2009-09-23

Can I do this or do I need to load all the values and then explode and compare the values in my DATETIME `start` field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LIKE in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_items WHERE start LIKE 'some-date%'
```

You put a % sign as a wildcard.

Be aware though that like can be a very heavy query. Specially if you use % at the start of a string.

Comment: What amount of rows would it get heavy at?

Comment: It depends on the system. If you're worried. Then look at the slow query log (if you have it on)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with dates, like it seems you are saying :

> Where start would be a DATETIME field
>   with data like 2009-09-23 11:34:00 and
>   $date would be something like
>   2009-09-23

Using LIKE might not be the only/best solution : there are functions that deal with dates ; and you probably can use comparison operators too.

In your case, you can probably use something like this :

```
select * 
from headers_sites 
where date_fetch >= '2009-07-15' 
limit 0, 10
```

Of course, you'll have to adapt this query to your tables/fields ; something like this might do, I suppose :

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_items WHERE start >= '$date'
```

This will get you every data for which the date is more recent than $date.

If you only want the date of one day, this could do :

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule_items 
WHERE start >= '$date'
    and start < adddate('$date', interval 1 day)
```

This might be better than "like", if you start column has an index -- not sure, though ; but, still, what you are willing to get will be obvious from your query... And that is nice.

Comment: Can I do this in this manner: SELECT * FROM `schedule_items` WHERE `start` = '$ymd' event though for sure... $ymd will be a YYYY-MM-DD and.. `start` will be a YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00

Comment: No you cannot : as you said, one side of the = sign will have 00:00:00 ; you'll match on a second-basis, and not by day -- ie, you won't match much.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL you can use LIKE instead of `=` and then you get the `%` wildcard. Example:

```
select ... where start like "2009-09-%";
```

(That would match anything from August 2009)

Comment: So my date I want to match is 2009-10-09 or whatever stored in $ymd can do i LIKE "$ymd %"

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just make sure you mysql_real_escape_string() anything you got from the user before putting it into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If it is needed to extract records of a date from datetime field, you need to use following format:

`SELECT * FROM schedule_items WHERE date(start) = 'some-date time'`

Comment: Hi LittlePanda, just need to ask what did you edit? it seems like same as i wrote...